# Datatable Server Side Ajax from API URL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I make a GET to an API, then I got 1000 accounts.

My sample data : https://jsonblob.com/57c08bb2e4b0dc55a4f0eec7

---

Since [Datatable website](https://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) suggested, here is my settings

```
var account_table =  $('#account-table').DataTable({
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php",
  "deferLoading": 10,

});
```

For "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php", since I am using API, can I just do

"ajax": "https://jsonblob.com/57c08bb2e4b0dc55a4f0eec7" ????

Will it work ? I hope someone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is to get the data and instead of putting ajax data put something like this

```
    var accounts;
    $.ajax({
         url: "https://jsonblob.com/57c08bb2e4b0dc55a4f0eec7",
      }).done(function(data) {
         accounts = data.data;
       }); 
     var account_table =  $('#account-table').DataTable({
       "processing": true,
       "serverSide": true,
       "ajax": accounts,
       "deferLoading": 10,

      });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - mate :)

Comment: Hey, how comes when I include `"deferLoading": 10,` I got `No matching records found` ?

Comment: When I don't include, it show all 1000 of them, but I only want to load 10 at the first glance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that as part of your answer - please?

Comment: [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html) look this

Comment: or try add this in your table `data-page-length="10"`

Comment: "data-page-length":10 is the correct syntax, and it still show 1000.

Comment: Should I be using something like [this](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html)

Comment: tries to change data by ajax

Comment: What do you mean ? ?? Can u update your answer or something ?